# turning array into property value recursivly

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm using an api that returns single value properties as arrays.  I'd like to have it so that if there's only 1 value in the array, the value should be a string rather than an array of strings.

I've created the snippet below, but I'm getting "maximum call stack size exceeded" Obviously I'm in a loop, but I'm not quite sure how to break out of it. Any suggestions on how to recursivly map the object and accomplish my example below?

```
    const original = {
        a: ['foo'],
        b: ['bar'],
        c:{
            d:['baz'],
            e:['buzz'],
            f:{
                g:['zip'],
                h:['zap']
            }
        }
    };

    exampleResult = {
        a:"foo",
        b:"bar",
        c:{
            d:"baz",
            e:"buzz",
            f:{
                g:"zip",
                h:"zap"
            }
        }
    }

    function transformer(item){
        return _.transform(original, (r, v, k) => {

            if(typeof v ==="object"){
            transformer(v[0])
            }
            if(Array.isArray(v)){
            r[k] = v[0];  
            }
        });
    }
    let result = transformer(original)
    console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const original = {
    a: ['foo'],
    b: ['bar'],
    c:{
        d:['baz'],
        e:['buzz'],
        f:{
            g:['zip'],
            h:['zap']
        }
    }
};

function transform(o) {
    const transformed = {};
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(o)) {
        transformed[key] = Array.isArray(value) ? value[0] : transform(value);
    }
    return transformed;
}

console.log(transform(original));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function transform(item) {
    for (var key in item) {
        if (typeof item[key] === 'object') {
            if (Array.isArray(item[key])) {
                item[key] = item[key][0];
            } else {
                transform(item[key]);
            }
        }
    }
    return item;
}

let result = transform(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(original)));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by always transferring `original` to the `_.transform()` here:

```
return _.transform(original, (r, v, k)
```

Every loop of the recursion returns to the original object, and starts again. To fix pass `item`:

```
return _.transform(item, (r, v, k)
```

You also need to fix your logic. Arrays are objects as well, so you need to check for arrays first. If the current value is an array, and it's length is 1, assign `val` the 1st item. If not, use the entire value.

Now check if `val` is an object, and if it is apply `transformer`.

```js
const transformer = item =>
  _.transform(item, (r, v, k) => {
    // extract 1st item in case if an array with a single item     
    const val = _.isArray(v) && v.length === 1 ? v[0] : v;
    
    // check if the handle value is an object and transform accordingly
    r[k] = _.isObject(val) ? transformer(val) : val;
  });

const original = {
  a: ['foo'],
  b: ['bar'],
  c: {
    d: ['baz'],
    e: ['buzz', 'nick', 'nack'],
    f: {
      g: ['zip'],
      h: ['zap']
    }
  }
};

const result = transformer(original);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```